# unable to get property reference from other C# project in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created `one c# library project`.
I have created `another MVC application added C# project reference into mvc application`.

Now on `View` I want to access that property which is there inside C# class library project but I'm unable to do so why?

C# project code

```
namespace Helper.BaseClasses
{
    public abstract class BaseView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
    {
        private TestClass localizer;

        public override void InitHelpers()
        {
            base.InitHelpers();
            localizer = new TestClass();
        }

        public TestClass Lang
        {
            get { return localizer; }
        }
    }
}


public class TestClass 
{
 public string TestMethod(string input)
        {
//some code
}
}
```

Mvc application added reference dll of c# 
Index.cshtml

```
<h4>@Lang.TestMethod("Customer agreements", "")</h4>
```

When I tried to use `TestMethod` in Index.cshtml it is given me error

> The name TestMethod does not exist in current context

after adding C# project dll reference why I'm getting this error :(

Comment: which version of MVC are you using ? and what is this "@Lang.TestMethod" ?

Comment: try to reference your dll with using clause inside your View. @using ProjectName.DLLName.BaseClasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set "pageBaseType" in web.config? 
If not, try to set it to your base class. 
To do that you need to find "pages" tag in *~/Views/web.config*. 
It would be something like:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

You need to change it to:

```
<pages pageBaseType="Helper.BaseClasses.BaseView">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

And rebuild solution.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot I make sense now :) can you give me any thread which explain this in details ?

Comment: The good intro is: [Changing Base Type Of A Razor View](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/)

Comment: Also i can recommend a book [Professional ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118794753)
In Chapter 16 [Advanced Topics] you can find more info about views compilation and customization.